# Make syncronous request, output, breaks via AJAX&PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, extjs, synchronization

*Hi all!*

I have some question and some trouble.

I don't want listen that it's impossible, but...

I'm writing some code in PHP & ExtJS & Jquery, which can make syncronous operations.
I need to connect a server-side (server under apache) and client part (using apc) and create syncronous ajax call to browser on client side.

**Example:**

OOP object (PHP 5) have following event:  on query (POST[query]) is equals 'test' he send:

```
EX: var d = prompt('test it!');
```

i need break php execution while do not get 'd' value and resend to http server.

After user will input something... PHP is waking up and performs operations (input/output).

**I need your advice, how to break php execution, get output at ajax responceText (js eval) and return specified by user (in browser) value on server and output d (for example).**

**Script php must executing code, which will follow after "break" (while)**

`While(<cond.. time, or exp>)` - have very terrible execution - no perfomance (.. maybe it have some other ways of using ..). But while() do not printing a text (because header not formed, while script is execute)

I'm waiting code examples

I think it very hard. But i hope, anybody can advice me smth....

Comment: you have to try restating your question. didn't understand what you want

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Your question makes little sense as is.  Can you provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish?  Synchronous AJAX requests are a bad idea, as everything blocks until the server responds.  Blocking PHP is difficult and doesn't make much sense to do.  It almost sounds as if you are trying to build some bidirectional communication or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following into your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'your_url',
            async: false,
       ...
```